# Windows 7 Backup not recognizing volume mounted on a subdirectory

Tags: windows-7, backup

I have a disk 1 called g: with a subdirectory called "otherG" where I've mounted another hard drive 2.
When I try to backup the g: drive, it does not show the subdirectory "otherG".
Also, the backup utility is not showing me disk 2 as an option for backing up separetely.

Is there a way to backup disks mounted on subdirectories?